# Can i search from 1 mysql column all results with 2 or more hits?

Tags: php, mysql

Okey, so i have basic search script in my site and it is working well. But I was thinking is it even possible (trying to google for 1 day, and 0 relevant topics found) to create this kind of search:

I got column named number. There is 5 numbers from 1-30 in every row. I would like to create search engine where i can enter 5 numbers and get results of every row which has at least 2 of those specific numbers (so eliminate the ones where only 1 can be found).

Any help you can give me, just tell is it possible and maybe some starters, or even some basic elements of the code if you can. I´m pretty new to the php/mysql world but learning fast

Edit: Thank you for notes: So the numbers are all in 1 column. They are separated with , and they from smallest to largest.

example: 3,6,9,13,22

When i search numbers: 3,7,9,11,27 this row wont show up, when i search 2,6,9,14,28 this row will show up

Comment: You say 5 numbers in every row... Is each number in a different column? Is it one column with comma separated numbers (2, 24, 12)? Are the numbers in any particular order?

Comment: I think If you leave some examples of the tables and the result your getting (and what you do expect) would help a LOT..

Comment: Since you are a new member, I will point you to the "How to ask a good question" FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . This question could have greatly benefited from a better description/example of your tables, and some examples of things that you have tried. Something besides "I searched Google" would have likely prevented the downvotes.

Answer (score 3):

One peculiarity of MySQL is that true and false are exactly the *integers* 1 and 0 respectively.

I know, it's weird, but this means you can add up boolean terms and the sum is the number of terms that evaluated to true.

For example, to search for the presence of at least two numbers from the list 1, 3, 7, 11, 17:

```
SELECT * FROM `no_one_ever_names_their_table_when_asking_sql_questions`
WHERE (1 IN (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)
    +  3 IN (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)
    +  7 IN (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)
    + 11 IN (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)
    + 17 IN (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)) >= 2
```

One caveat is that this booleans-are-integers trick doesn't work in standard SQL, so don't expect it to work in other brands of SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

You could store it just as 5 columns (`numcol1`, ..., `numcol5`). Then you can find matching rows with

```
WHERE 2 <= if(find_in_set(numcol1, '12,25,7') > 0, 1, 0) +  if(find_in_set(numcol2, '12,25,7') > 0, 1, 0) + ...
```

or a bit more compact, cryptic and cool:

```
WHERE 2 <= ((find_in_set(numcol1, '12,25,7') > 0) + (find_in_set(numcol2, '12,25,7') > 0 ) + ... )
```

You could also use a Bitset, but then your application has to ensure that only 5 values are set:

```
create table test (id int(11) not null auto_increment primary key, 
                   numbers SET('1','2','3',...,'30');
```

Then you split the user's input into numbers `us1`, `us2`, ..., `us5` and you have

```
select * from test where
2 <= ((0 < find_in_set($us1, numbers)) + (0 < find_in_set($us2, numbers)) + ... )
```

[SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html) is a BITSET and quite fast.